# LINQ: How do I select unique rows: max(id) with multiple columns?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

This is a "toy" example of a table that has many columns and 100s of thousands of rows.

I want *FILTER OUT* any rows containing the same AcctNo, CustomerName and CustomerContact, but KEEP the ID for *ONE* of the duplicates (so I can access the record later).

- Example:

  ```
  ID  AcctNo  CustomerName  CustomerContact
  1   1111    Acme Foods    John Smith
  2   1111    Acme Foods    John Smith
  3   1111    Acme Foods    Judy Lawson
  4   2222    YoyoDyne Inc  Thomas Pynchon
  5   2222    YoyoDyne Inc  Thomas Pynchon
  <= For AcctNo 1111, I want to save IDs 2 and 3
  ```
- Fiddle:
  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bEECHi6XnvKAeXC4Xthrrr/1
- Working SQL:

  ```
  select max(id) as ID,AcctNo,CustomerName,CustomerContact
  from test
  where AcctNo = '11111'
  group by AcctNo,CustomerName,CustomerContact
  ```

  OK: returns IDs 2 and 3:

  ```
  ID AcctNo CustomerName CustomerContact
  -- ------ ------------ ---------------
  2  11111  Acme Foods   John Smith
  3  11111  Acme Foods   Judy Lawson
  ```

Q: What's a LINQ equivalent for this SQL?

- Failed attempt:

  ```
  IQueryable<CustomerData> query =
      from c in context.CustomerData
      where c.AcctNo == acctno
      group c by new { c.AcctNo , c.CustomerName, c.CustomerContact } into gcs
      select new { newID = gcs.Max(x => x.ID), gcs.AcctNo, gcs.CustomerName, gcs.CustomerContact }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it right. Just access the group properties using Key in your projection.

```
IQueryable<CustomerData> query =
    from c in context.CustomerData
    where c.AcctNo == acctno
    group c by new { c.AcctNo , c.CustomerName, c.CustomerContact } into gcs
    select new { newID = gcs.Max(x => x.ID), gcs.Key.AcctNo, gcs.Key.CustomerName, gcs.Key.CustomerContact }
```

Answer (score 1):

First create a custom DTO view model similar to this

```
public CustomerViewModel
{
   public string AcctNo { get; set; }
   public string CustomerName { get; set; }
   public string CustomerContact { get; set; }
   public int MaxId { get; set; }
}
```

The query

```
context.CustomerData.Where(c => c.AcctNo == "1111")
       .GroupBy(c => new { c.AcctNo , c.CustomerName, c.CustomerContact })
       .Select(cg => new CustomerViewModel {
                      AcctNo  = cg.Key.AcctNo,
                      CustomerName  = cg.Key.CustomerName,
                      CustomerContact  = cg.Key.CustomerContact,
                      MaxId = cg.Max(c => c.ID)
        })
```

Comment: 1) The part I was missing was "c.Key.xxx". 2) What I want to do in my "real" program is pass one result to another ASP.Net Core page.  I was thinking of doing this by serializing the row to JSON, then calling the new page with the JSON string.  Your "DTO" idea would simplify this.  Thank you on both counts!